# How to reference cell data on CellFactory?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `TableView` where the last column is an "Action" column, containing a custom `ActionBox` object, with buttons for several actions. To add behaviour to this `ActionBox`, I need to pass a `Data` object to it. However, I don't know how to reference the object.

```java
class TableViewWithActionColumn() {
     @FXML TableColumn<Data, Void> actionColumn;

     public TableViewWithActionColumn() {
          // Code for loading custom component...
     }

     @FXML 
     public void initialize() {
          populateActionColumn();
     }

     private void populateActionColumn() {
        Callback<TableColumn<Data, Void>, TableCell<Data, Void>> cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn<Data, Void>, TableCell<Data, Void>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Data, Void> call(final TableColumn<Data, Void> param) {

                return new TableCell<Data, Void>() {
                    private final ActionBox actionBox = new ActionBox();

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        if (empty) {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        } else {
                            setGraphic(actionBox);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        actionColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
    }
}
```

I assumed that the reference to the object was in `Void item`, so I tried replacing all occurrences of `Void` with `Data`, and doing `setGraphic(new ActionBox(item));`, but this led to a NullPointerException, so I suppose that's not the right way to do it. So, how do I reference row's data in CellFactory context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TableCell` has a [`getTableRow()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html#getTableRow()) method, that gives you a reference to the `TableRow` that contains the cell. The `TableRow` is itself a cell implementation, so you can call its `getItem()` method to get the data represented by the row.

In context (and removing all the unnecessary boilerplate from your code):

```
private void populateActionColumn() {
    actionColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Data, Void>() {
        private final ActionBox actionBox = new ActionBox();

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                Data rowData = getTableRow().getItem();
                // ... something like: actionBox.setData(rowData) ; 
                setGraphic(actionBox);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! After your comment, I tried to do it myself, but I was calling `getTableRow().getItem()` before checking for emptiness, which was leding me to another `NullPointerException` 

But now, one more question: is there a difference in behaviour doing it like this: 
`private final ActionBox actionBox = new ActionBox();`

And like this?
`else { Data rowData = getTableRow().getItem(); ActionBox actionBox = new ActionBox(rowData); setGraphic(actionBox); }`

I'm doing it the second way, because as I said, I need to pass the data to my ActionBox.

Comment: @AllanJuan `updateItem()` can be called frequently (e.g. during scrolling), but cells are only created rarely (typically when the table is first created, and possibly later only if it is resized). So it's generally much more efficient to create UI components on which the cell depends once only for each cell, and then to configure them in `updateItem()` using the data provided.

Comment: So I would instantiate `ActionBox` outside `updateItem()`, as you did, and then do something like `actionBox.setData(data)` inside `updateItem()`? In my head, that would lead to a reference problem (all rows referencing the same `ActionBox`)

Comment: @AllanJuan No, because there is a different `TableCell` instance in each visible row. The `ActionBox` is a property of the *cell*, not of the *cellFactory*.